# Proxy RPC through apache (port 443) while keeping SSL webpage too

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, proxy, ssl, rpc

I run a RPC daemon in port 443 which talks in JSON format, I'd like to keep it in that port as to prevent being blocked by firewalls.

The server also has a HTTP webpage (port 80) which I'd like to upgrade to use SSL..

Here lies the problem, since you can't run 2 services under the same TCP port, is it possible to filter traffic just using apache and proxy it to the service? if so, how would I setup apache to identify the JSON data?

Example raw RPC request:

```
{"method":"login","params":{"login":"admin","pass":"password","agent":"testing"},"id":1}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can still do TLS/SSL over port 80, right?

Comment: @mtak I wouldn't like to go off standard. that would require people to use my site at `https://example.com:80` wich looks horrible

Comment: That'd probably be good to mention in your question then ;)